# Resources exceded in Big Query - Why would that happen?

Tags: sql, performance, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to include many sub-queries in a single query and then trying to merge 3 of the sub-queries using the join operations. The subqueries run well when ran alone, but the joining of the three is just not happening.

[image: Resources exceded]

I have faced similar bottlenecks in the past, would want to know ways of avoiding the problem or atleast why it appears at the first place.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try doing in steps as the query produced a join explosion.

Comment: You probably have bad join conditions that are creating multiple intermediate tables.

Answer (score 0):

Bigquery can only handle a certain amount of subqueries.
It mainly has problems using order by / over partition by functions, since they all have to be evaluated against every other value.

You could try optimizing your query by getting rid of those kind of evaluations.
Another possibility is to materialize some of your subqueries into different tables.

For specifics; please look into this:
https://medium.com/enkel-digital/googles-big-query-resources-exceeded-during-query-execution-%EF%B8%8F-13c20b6693e2

Comment: I have written queries in BigQuery with thousands of lines, many subqueries and CTEs, and generous use of window functions.  I don't know what your answer is trying to communicate.